# Will sdcard0 be encrypted on HTC One XL?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc, internal-sd, encryption

If I want to connect to our company Exchange server I am forced to encrypt my android (cm11).

- **Q1) My question is whether ever /sdcard0 will be encrypted too.**

*Note that HTC One XL got only internal storeage, no external SD card is present.*

That is the location where I got pictures taken, installers for cm etc.

- **Q2)** if /sdcard0 is encrypted too will I be able to access the files on sdcard0 via Mass Storage?
- **Q3)** from the research I did, I would be able to update cm using "using a tmpfs mount for /sdcard and 'adb push update.zip /sdcard' just seconds flashing". Is that correct?
- **Q4)** if I update cm will the data on /sdcard0 be still accessible?
- **Q5)** I read that the only way to decrypt android phone is factory reset. That's something I do always before installing new version of cm. But this does not touch any data on /sdcard0. If /sdcard0 is encrypted what is the way for me to decrypt my phone?

Comment: Not answering your question, but there are mail clients ([mailwise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syntomo.email&hl=en), [for example](http://mail-wise.com/faq/#bypass)) that allow you to connect to exchange and bypass the exchange security settings.

Answer (score 2):

Too many questions btw but the answers are follows :

**Ans 1 :** Yes your `/sdcard0` will be encrypted.

**Ans 2 :** No, if the `/sdcard0` is encrypted you will not be able to access your storage in anyway.

**Ans 3 :** Yes, you will be able to update your `cm` but it will not be updated in seconds, it will take **several minutes**.

**Ans 4 :** Yes, all your previous data will be accessible. Data is lost only if you are installing `cm` for the first time, if you are updating it, your data will not be lost.

**Ans 5 :** Upto I know, you can decrypt your phone without factory reset but I don't know step by step process for decryption.

Comment: Ans4: how come data is going to be lost when I install cm for the first time? Let's say I got cm installed now and I decide to encrypt. So I just update settings and the phone will be updated. I am confused about this answer. On the other hand what is going to happen after I upgraded cm on encrypted phone? It will just pick it up and will be able to access the encrypted part?

Comment: @Radek What he means is that if you install from stock to CM ROM. You will obviously lose all data, since you are recommended to do a full wipe. But if you upgrade existing CM to a minor CM update, you can retain your data.